# Do I need to be careful about PPU and Camera size and Device Resolution even if I'm not creaing a pixel art 2d game?

Tags: unity, 2d

I was reading this blog post
https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/06/19/pixel-perfect-2d/
and was wondering if I need to be super careful about those numbers, although my game's art is not pixel art.

Comment: Beware of link rot! Please include the relevant part(s) of the other page to the core of the question. If the other page gets taken down, your question will make no sense and be useless for future visitors.

Comment: There are very few things in games that you "need" to do. No 2D art police will arrest you or forbid you from releasing your game if you don't follow the rules. The real question is, would doing something differently better suit your goals for your specific game? To answer that, we'd need to know what specific aspect of your game you're thinking you might be able to improve through camera/PPU/resolution adjustments. If you have a particular visual that doesn't look right on certain devices, try including screenshots of these symptoms and details we can use to diagnose the issue.

Comment: I have nothing specific in mind. But just wanted to make sure I'm learning to do things right. (I've just started to learn unity). I guess I already have my answer, and the techniques mentioned in that blog posts are only for pixel art games, otherwise you would answer differently. Is that correct?

Comment: As DMGregory mentioned, you are free to choose how you render things. For 2D pixel art, it is generally desirable that sprites are rendered exactly as they were designed (as pixel art is designed pixel-by-pixel). If scaling occurs during rendering, 2D pixel art will often look incorrect. From personal experience, I think vector graphics and 3D graphics suffer less from this problem, as they are not designed to be rendered at a specific size, whereas pixel art is.